# ASP.NET Image preload

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I want to preload an image to prevent screen flashing... Every second the URL is different.
I have tried this, but i can't see anything in my ASP:Image control...

```
public void loadImage(string url)
{
    pictureBox3.ImageUrl = url;
    Thread.Sleep(200);
    pictureBox2 = pictureBox3.;
}
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: what does the Page_Load code look like Ferry...?`pictureBox2 = pictureBox3.;` are you wanting to assign the ImageUrl of pictureBox3 to pictureBox2..? also this can't possibly compile the way that you have it you have a `.` at the end of pictureBox3 `pictureBox3.;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `Thread.Sleep`, you're halting what's happening *on the server*; that has a consequence on the client, but only of delaying yet some more and *then* still incurring the cost of the image download in presence of the user (though it might not always be noticeable).

To do this, look into using some [client-side script](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to issue [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) requests as necessary, these calls can go on asynchronously in the background while the user is viewing the web page, and, so long as the request is always ahead of the change (which you should make it so, by making the change occur only when an image request has completed), you can update the image by doing the replace (by updating the client markup, the `src` of the image, rather than server-side changes).

Comment: Okay, i will figure this out.. Thanks!